# Inherited Apps Script onOpen function not working on cloned Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am using the Drive API, authenticated via a service account, to copy a "master" Google Sheet that has an Apps Script attached. The Apps Script is simple and creates a custom menu in the Google Sheet. However, when the Google Sheet is copied from Drive and then accessed via the Google Sheets API, the attached apps script doesn't execute the `onOpen` function. I'm guessing there is some strange ownership/permissions issue that is preventing the `onOpen` from "activating" when it's copied with the service account and then given domain-wide "write" permissions.

Comment: It isn't "strange" - the Apps Script project is entirely new in the copied document, and as such it will not and can not be executed without prior approval. Publish a domain-wide add-on, and install it in your domain. Then it is only one file, doesn't get copied, and needs only to be approved once (and then added to each document as appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

On open events, simple and installable, are triggered only when a user opens a spreadsheet not by API actions.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/